# Order of subgroups and number of elements of order $3$ in a group of order $9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $9$.
>
> 1) State the possible orders of subgroups and elements in $G$.
>
> 2) Find the number of elements of $G$ of order $3$ in the cases where (a) $G$ is
>   non-cyclic, (b) $G$ is cyclic.

I have a problem with the (b). Here is what I did so far, is it right ?

We know that for G a group of finite order, $\forall H \leq G$ then $\vert H \vert $ divides $\vert G\vert$. $G$ has order $9 =3*3=1*9$, so the possible order of subgroups and elements in $G$ are 3 and 9.

a) If $G$ is not cyclic then there can't be an element $a\in G$ such that $<a>=G$ ie there is not $a\in G$ with $\vert a \vert = \vert G \vert = 9$ so the number of elements in $G$ of order 3 is 2.

b) If $G$ is cyclic then I guess the are none (probably because the only order possible is then 9, but I don't see how to prove it properly.

Thanks

Comment: (a) is wrong: if $\;G\;$ isn't cyclic then **all** the non-unity elements have order $\;3\;$ ...(hint: Lagrange)

Comment: If we think of "a cyclic group of order $n$" as "the group of $n^{th}$ roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$", then (b) is very easily understandable, rather than considering "abstract cyclic group of order 9". (It is quite well know, but may be non-trivial for beginner, that for each divisor of order of a finite cyclic group, there is unique subgroup of order equal to that divisor.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

(1) For $\;G\;$ cyclic, $\;|G|=n\;$ : for any divisor $\;d\;$ of $\;n\;$, there's *exactly* one unique subgroup of $\;G\;$ of order $\;d\;$ which, of course, is also cyclic.

(2) A cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ always has $\;\phi(n)\;$ elements of order $\;n\;$ (and thus also generators of the whole group).

Comment: (1)Alright, so for $G$ cyclic there is only two subgroups : the identity of order 1 and another subgroup, say $H$ of order 9 ?
(2) what do you mean by $\phi (n)$ ?

Comment: Eulers phi function...i.e. number of positive integers less than $n$ and relatively prime to $n$

Comment: Nice one I did not know it ! I guess we'll see it later in the course. Though it did not apply here I think as it is a group of order 9 and we wanted the subgroups of order 3. I'll keep in mind !

Comment: About your first question, @Hypem : no, a cyclic group of order 9 has exactly three subgroups, of orders $\;1,3,9\;$ ...

Comment: Sure, I skipped $3$... Thanks again